# Difference of convex functions optimization problem in R

Tags: convex-optimization, r

I am seeking of any already written R package which could help in an optimization technique which is called  Difference of convex functions. This technique is sketched [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-097-prediction-machine-learning-and-statistics-spring-2012/projects/MIT15_097S12_proj5.pdf) and could be very useful for reinforcement learning processes.

Does anyone know something, that could be helpful? 
I have found [package called **cccp**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cccp/index.html), but it is all about conic optimization and I don't understand now how could it be used for such a problem.

I would like to solve the following (a bit simplified) minimization problem, which decomposes in difference of two convex functions:

$$\min_\mathbf{w} S(\mathbf{w}) =\min_\mathbf{w} \sum_{i=1}^{n}  \min ( \dfrac{|X_i\mathbf{w}|}{\phi}, 1) =  \min_\mathbf{w}~ (S_1(\mathbf{w}) - S_2(\mathbf{w}))$$

$$S_1(\mathbf{w}) =  \sum_{i=1}^{n}  \dfrac{|X_i\mathbf{w}|}{\phi} $$

$$S_2(\mathbf{w}) =  \sum_{i=1}^{n}    \left( \dfrac{|X_i\mathbf{w}|}{\phi} - 1   \right)^+$$

where $(x)^+ = \max(x, 0)$

If you have any suggestions or useful related links with any examples, they would be very appreciated.

PS. I have found that difference of convex functions optimization problem is closely related with "concave-convex optimization procedure" (CCCP). If anyone has thoughts of how the aforementioned problem could be solved by CCCP, please share!